# Tour of Go exercise #22: Reader, what does the question mean?

Tags: go

[Exercise: Readers](https://tour.golang.org/methods/22)

Implement a Reader type that emits an infinite stream of the ASCII character 'A'.

I don't understand the question, how to emit character 'A'? into which variable should I set that character?

Here's what I tried:

```
package main

import "golang.org/x/tour/reader"

type MyReader struct{}

// TODO: Add a Read([]byte) (int, error) method to MyReader.

func main() {
    reader.Validate(MyReader{}) // what did this function expect?
}

func (m MyReader) Read(b []byte) (i int, e error) {
    b = append(b, 'A') // this is wrong..
    return 1, nil      // this is also wrong..
}
```

Comment: Read should read the data to a supplied buffer, not append to it.

Comment: answers: https://gist.github.com/inancgumus/d25d045b4cec43dcbb111e04980d396b

Comment: Got the same issue, this Go exercise is very confusing.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Ah I understand XD

I think it would be better to say: "rewrite all values in `[]byte` into `'A'`s"

```
package main

import "golang.org/x/tour/reader"

type MyReader struct{}

// TODO: Add a Read([]byte) (int, error) method to MyReader.
func (m MyReader) Read(b []byte) (i int, e error) {
    for x := range b {
        b[x] = 'A'
    }
    return len(b), nil
}

func main() {
    reader.Validate(MyReader{})
}
```

Comment: You could do it almost as your original implementation too, and just supply 1 byte at a time, i.e. `b[0] = 'A'  return 1, nil`

Comment: @nos Using `b[0] = 'A'` should come with a length check: `if len(b) > 0 {b[0] = 'A'}` which is implicit in case of using `for ... range`.

Comment: A basic error I had encountered was I used _double quotes_ ("A") to assign to the `[]byte` instead of _single quotes_ ('A'). Turns out in GoLang, *'A'* represents a single character i.e a Unicode code point whereas *"A"* represents a sequence of characters.

Answer (score 4):

An `io.Reader.Read` role is to write a given memory location with data read from its source.

To implement a stream of `'A'`, the function must write given memory location with `'A'` values.

It is not required to fill in the entire slice provided in input, it can decide how many bytes of the input slice is written ([`Read reads up to len(p) bytes into p`](https://pkg.go.dev/io#Reader)), it must return that number to indicate to the consumer the length of data to process.

By convention an `io.Reader` indicates its end by returning an [`io.EOF`](https://pkg.go.dev/io#pkg-variables) error. If the reader does not return an error, it behaves as an infinite source of data to its consumer which can never detect an exit condition.

Note that a call to `Read` that returns `0 bytes` read can happen and does not indicate anything particular, [`Callers should treat a return of 0 and nil as indicating that nothing happened;`](https://pkg.go.dev/io#Reader) Which makes this non-solution https://play.golang.org/p/aiUyc4UDYi2 fails with a timeout.

In regard to that, the solution provided here https://stackoverflow.com/a/68077578/4466350 `return copy(b, "A"), nil` is really just right. It writes the minimum required, with an elegant use of built-ins and syntax facilities, and it never returns an error.

Answer (score 2):

Simplest one:

```golang
func (s MyReader) Read(b []byte) (int, error) {
    b[0] = byte('A')
    return 1, nil
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can generalize the idea to create an eternal reader, `alwaysReader`, from which you always read the same byte value over and over (it never results in EOF):

```
package readers

type alwaysReader struct {
    value byte
}

func (r alwaysReader) Read(p []byte) (n int, err error) {
    for i := range p {
        p[i] = r.value
    }
    return len(p), nil
}

func NewAlwaysReader(value byte) alwaysReader {
    return alwaysReader { value }
}
```

`NewAlwaysReader()` is the constructor for `alwaysReader` (which isn't exported). The result of `NewAlwaysReader('A')` is a reader from whom you will always read `'A'`.

A clarifying unit test for `alwaysReader`:

```
package readers_test

import (
    "bytes"
    "io"
    "readers"
    "testing"
)

func TestEmptyReader(t *testing.T) {
    const numBytes = 128
    const value = 'A'

    buf := bytes.NewBuffer(make([]byte, 0, numBytes))
    reader := io.LimitReader(readers.NewAlwaysReader(value), numBytes)

    n, err := io.Copy(buf, reader)
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatal("copy failed: %w")
    }
    if n != numBytes {
        t.Errorf("%d bytes read but %d expected", n, numBytes)
    }
    for i, elem := range buf.Bytes() {
        if elem != value {
            t.Errorf("byte at position %d has not the value %v but %v", i, value, elem)
        }
    }
}
```

Since we can read from the `alwaysReader` forever, we need to decorate it with a [`io.LimitReader`](https://pkg.go.dev/io#LimitedReader) so that we end up reading at most `numBytes` from it. Otherwise, the `bytes.Buffer` will eventually run out of memory for reallocating its internal buffer because of [`io.Copy()`](https://pkg.go.dev/io#Copy).

Note that the following implementation of `Read()` for `alwaysReader` is also valid:

```
func (r alwaysReader) Read(p []byte) (n int, err error) {
    if len(p) > 0 {
        p[0] = r.value
        return 1, nil
    }
    return 0, nil
}
```

The former `Read()` implementation fills the whole byte slice with the byte value, whereas the latter writes a single byte.

Answer (score 0):

The alleged answer is didn't work for me, even without the typos.
Try as I did, that string would not go into b.

```golang
func (r MyReader) Read(b []byte) (int,  error) {
    return copy(b, "A"), nil
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution: just add one byte at a time, store the index `i` using closure.

```
package main

import (
    "golang.org/x/tour/reader"
)

type MyReader struct{}

func (mr MyReader) Read(b []byte) (int, error) {
    i := 0
    p := func () int {
        b[i] = 'A'
        i += 1
        
        return i
    }
    
    
    return p(), nil
}

func main() {
    reader.Validate(MyReader{})
}
```

Comment: it does not `add one byte at a time`, it simply assign `b[0]` with the value `'A'`.